# Random-ая генерация цвета в Sass

Tags: ruby, css, sass, ruby-on-rails

Мне нужно сгенерировать HTML элементы, которые имели бы рандомный `background-color`.

Нашел как это сделать в [Ruby](http://victorcoulon.fr/generating-random-color-in-sass/)

Но не понимаю как привязать Ruby метод к своему приложению

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def getRandomColor()
    Sass::Script::String.new("#%06x" % (rand * 0xffffff))
  end
end
```

Написано что надо этот код вставить в файл `config.rb`, но в rails 3.2.8 такого файла нету, куда его тогда вставлять?

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать в config/application.rb поставить

или в libs создать файлик с этим текстом